# What to use ,MooTools morph, jQuery animate, jq hover() or something else?

Tags: jquery, mootools

I have a group of elements in a container that are all hidden on page load. They are hidden by negative absolute positions which I would like to animate onhover.

I can use either libraries jq or moo

and trying to  get similar effect webshop on hover effect
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/category/home?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon

you can see latency on extension slider navigation ( pops from sides)  and its info ( pops from bottom)

this is very simple moo version with no latency

http://jsfiddle.net/BVjna/38/

the issue I have with that, either by using moo morph , or jq animate is that I have to list each of the divs inside the container because they will have different absolute position.

what I would rather have is a class applied to .container and morph/animate the inside elements by css , kinda like  `.container.hovered .el1{top:0;}` but of course with animation effect .

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Use jQuery, because it's the most popular. Meaning it's the easiest to look up any questions you might have about it.

Answer (score 1):

I have absolutely 0 experience with mootools, but I do know jquery. This is a very simple effect to mimic. (Although, I based mine mostly off google's store).

[Rollover Hovering Replacement Example @ jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qmnyH/4/)

The idea here is instead of having to work out the divs that are being slid over and dealing with thier absolute position you put them into a single container and roll that out.

This also solves the problem that you're aligning the start position of all elements at the same spot, so the relative velocities in your example produce an accordion effect (looks like a stretch instead of a slide).

As you can see it works on multiple controls too.

**Edit:** I also added an example of how to make the main content slide away (like google).

Comment: nice one but I have a small issue with that ,  in demo I aligned elements from top ect, but my actual code , has 7 elements and ALL have different positioning and should "enter" the container , left , right , top , bottom , your version just slides the container down, il edit my fiddle

Comment: Well you could always use DOM measurements and math but keep in mind, this is *SLOW* (the DOM measurements).

Answer (score -1):

Here is another option using CSS3 transitions.

http://jsfiddle.net/davesters81/VMxyw/2/

Would not work in older browsers though.  But shows you that you can achieve this without javascript or jQuery at all.